# protractor is not waiting for ui-router to change state

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ui-router

I'm using protractor for system tasting my ui-router SPA application.
As I understands the documentation, protractor should wait for things to happen before/while angular is playing.
for instance, when the user click a button, I'm changing the state. So I'm like -

```
$('#addProductButton button').click();
```

and then -

```
expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toContain('#/products/new');
```

but it fails.
To work around that I'm using browser.wait until the location is good. but this is stink.
**does someone knows why protractor is not waiting.**

p.s
try to use browser.waitForAngular() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I was using $provide.decorator to provide $httpbackend with some values, while using setTimeout instead of $timeout.
setTimeout got me out of angular world and protractor is not waiting for that.

njoy!